# Freeze android junit test after test execution

Tags: android, junit, android-testing

after each test execution junit goes to the next test. And activity closes automatically after each test execution.

Its OK when I test functions, but NOT OK when I test views. I want to see execution results on the screen before junit will execute next test.

So, I want to make small delay between tests.

---

There is one way I can do it:

```
public void testMyView() throws InterruptedException {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // viewOperations...
        }
    });
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

But I dont like this way because this code is dirty (especially when I have a lot of such tests).

---

Another way seems much better:

```
@UiThreadTest
public void testHandleEmptyAlphabetList() throws InterruptedException {
// view operations
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

BUT: It will block UI thread but NOT test thread. I need to block a test thread.

Is there any way to run `Thread.sleep(3000);` from this code separately in a test thread?

---

So, what is the best way to make thread delays between tests?

p.s. Please don't recommend me additional test frameworks, I want to solve my problem using embed tools. Thank you.

Comment: Try overriding tearDown() method and put `Thread.sleep(3000);` here.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest ditching this cumbersome way of unit testing and using [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/), so your tests run in the JVM and you don't have to deal with all this nasty setup. You'll be pleasantly surprised on how quickly your View testing runs, and that you don't need to run an emulator!

Comment: thanks, I know about Robolectric. But as I mentioned I want pure android and junit way

Answer (score -2):

Try to use [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) for the tests that need a real android running.

```
solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
[...]
if (failure) {
    solo.takeScreenshot();
}
```

This will save a screenshot to your SD card (needs WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission)

Or if you prefer not to use another testing framework (though I would recommend you take a look at it), just steal the code that is used there for taking screenshots